# Как динамически сформировать файл robots.txt?

Tags: .htaccess, php, robots.txt

Добрый день! Есть сайт (интернет-магазин) с множеством региональных версий, каждая региональная версия представлена на своём поддомене (например, moscow.mysite.ru, spb.mysite.ru, rostov.mysite.ru и т.д.), для сайта нужно выдавать разный robots.txt для каждого поддомена. Попытался делать так:

```
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} spb.mysite.ru [NC]
  RewriteRule ^robots\.txt /robots_spb.txt [NC,L]
```

не сработало. Затем подобным образом, но через php

```
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} spb.mysite.ru [NC]
  RewriteRule ^robots\.txt robots.php [L]
```

И опять ничего. Предпочтительный вариант был бы через php, но я не знаю, как его реализовать. Может кто-то сталкивался? Подскажите, как сделать.

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

В общем в .htaccess прописали

```
RewriteRule ^(robots\.txt)$ robots.php [L]
```

А в файле **robots.php** стоит такой код:

```
$region = strstr(str_ireplace("www.", "", $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]), ".", true);
if(file_exists("robots_".$region.".txt"))
    echo file_get_contents("robots_".$region.".txt");
else echo file_get_contents("robots.txt");
```

Т.е. считали регион из URL, проверили, есть ли отдельный robots для региона, если есть - подставили его, если нет - подставили общий для всего сайта robots.txt.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (file_exists('robots.txt'))
{
$text = "текст роботса";
$region = тут константой получаем регион, либо ниже
     $xnumer = explode(".", $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);
     if (strlen($xnumer[0]) == 3) // проверка на www
     {$region = $xnumer[1];}else{$region = $xnumer[0];}
$text = str_replace("{MY_REGION}", $region, $text);
$fp = fopen("robots.txt", "w");
fwrite($fp, $text);
fclose($fp);
}
```

Как вариант можно в index.php сделать инклудом проверку)) Все равно что в .htaccess проверка либо в пхп), особо сильной разницы не будет)

Comment: спасибо, попробую! )

Answer (score 1):

Не проверял, но примерно так должно получиться. Запомнить часть поддоменна и подставить её к фактическому имени файла.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+).mysite.ru [NC]
RewriteRule ^robots\.txt /robots_%1.txt [NC,L]
```

См. про "RewriteCond backreferences" в документации по [RewriteCond](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond).